# Truncated Pareto estimation

Tags: r, estimation, pareto-distribution

Given min and max values, how can I estimate shape parameter (tail index) of data generated by truncated pareto distribution ? I see a package tpareto but find no information on how to estimate tail index from given data.

Comment: Check the following simulated example: `set.seed(1);
data = rtpareto(100, 1,10,2);

ll = function(par){
if(par[1]>0&par[3]>0&par[2]>par[1]) return( -sum(log(dtpareto(data,par[1],par[2],par[3]))) )
else return(Inf)
};

optim(c(1,10,2),ll);` . (Requires VGAM)

Comment: thanks...any suggestion how can i estimate tail index if i dont know the actual tail index of generated data ?

Comment: Sorry, I posted the code for obtaining the joint estimators. Given min and max, you can estimate the shape parameter using this code `set.seed(1); 
data = rtpareto(100, 1,10,2); 

ll = function(par){ 
if(par>0) return( -sum(log(dtpareto(data,1,10,par))) ) 
else return(Inf) }; 

optimize(ll,c(1,3));`.

Comment: thanks a lot. should i interpret $minimum as value of tail index ? any reference/doc will be appreciated as I have no experience of optimization stuff which has been used above...thanks again

Comment: Yes, `$minimum` gives you the estimator. In this case the approach used is [MLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) and this value is called the Maximum Likelihood Estimator. The function `ll` is the negative of the log-likelihood. The optimisation is conducted using the command `optimize`. Information about the algorithm implemented in this command can be found [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/optimize.html). Theory about the estimation of the parameters of this distribution [here](http://www.stt.msu.edu/~mcubed/tpareto.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for this. It's really nice to see how simple the log-likelihood function is. The optimize() function is a search operation based on the parameter bounds it is given, shape parameter bounds in this case, while optim() is a general optimization search function with a reversed parameter order. The former only works for continuous functions, while the latter is often used with L-BFGS-B. The sgd package (stochastic gradient descent) may also be useful for the first function: combinatorial optimization. Since the surface is smooth/continuous, sparse approaches should be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Using `VGAM` truncated Pareto functions with `fitdistrplus`, the following should work:

```
lower <- min(data)
upper <- max(data)
fit   <- fitdist(data, 'truncpareto', start=list(lower=lower, upper=upper, shape=1))
```

This applies the Pareto bounds first to estimate the shape parameter before plugging it into the truncated Pareto MLE function. However, `truncpareto` has been giving me issues, so I cannot verify it yet.